# PayPal IPN for disputes/chargebacks

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, codeigniter-3, paypal-ipn

So I am working with the PayPal IPN for a payment gateway in my store project. Users can create stores and add a paypal gateway which is just storing their PayPal email.

How can I listen for chargebacks on that payment so I can then act upon that. Please note that I obviously do not have access to these paypal accounts, so I cannot setup a listener in their paypal.

When I create a payment I am building a query and then sending them to that URL, in that query is the notify_url, will that be used again if someone were to create a dispute on the payment. I tried to create a dispute however nothing seemed to happen to my database (What the notify url does).

Any help would be great. 
Here is a the codeigniter library I am using:

[CODE]
class Paypal {

```
var $config         = Array();
var $production_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?';
var $sandbox_url    = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?';
var $item           = 1;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param   string
 * @return  void
 */
public function __construct($props = array())
{
    $this->__initialize($props);
    log_message('debug', "Paypal Class Initialized");
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * initialize Paypal preferences
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   array
 * @return  bool
 */
function __initialize($props = array())
{
    $config["business"]     = ''; //Your PayPal account
    $config["cmd"]          = '_cart'; //Do not modify
    $config["production"]   = FALSE;
    #Custom variable here we send the billing code-->
    $config["custom"]       = '';
    $config["invoice"]      = '';
    #API Configuration-->
    $config["upload"]           = '1'; //Do not modify
    $config["currency_code"]    = 'GBP'; 
    $config["disp_tot"]         = 'Y';
    #Page Layout -->
    $config["cpp_header_image"]         = ''; //Image header url [750 pixels wide by 90 pixels high]
    $config["cpp_cart_border_color"]    = '000'; //The HTML hex code for your principal identifying color
    $config["no_note"]                  = 1; //[0,1] 0 show, 1 hide
    #Payment Page Information -->
    $config["return"]           = ''; //The URL to which PayPal redirects buyers’ browser after they complete their payments.
    $config["cancel_return"]    = ''; //Specify a URL on your website that displays a “Payment Canceled” page.
    $config["notify_url"]       = '';  //The URL to which PayPal posts information about the payment
    $config["rm"]               = '2'; //Leave this to get payment information
    $config["lc"]               = 'EN'; //Languaje [EN,ES]
    #Shipping and Misc Information -->
    $config["shipping"]             = '';
    $config["shipping2"]            = '';
    $config["handling"]             = '';
    $config["tax"]                  = '';
    $config["discount_amount_cart"] = ''; //Discount amount [9.99]
    $config["discount_rate_cart"]   = ''; //Discount percentage [15]
    #Customer Information -->
    $config["first_name"]           = '';
    $config["last_name"]            = '';
    $config["address1"]             = '';
    $config["address2"]             = '';
    $config["city"]                 = '';
    $config["state"]                = '';
    $config["zip"]                  = '';
    $config["email"]                = '';
    $config["night_phone_a"]        = '';
    $config["night_phone_b"]        = '';
    $config["night_phone_c"]        = '';

    /*
     * Convert array elements into class variables
     */
    if (count($props) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($props as $key => $val)
        {
            $config[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
    $this->config = $config;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Perform payment process
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   array
 * @return  void
 */
function pay(){

    #Convert the array to url encode variables
    $vars =  http_build_query($this->config);
    if($this->config['production'] == TRUE){
        header('LOCATION:'.$this->production_url.$vars);
    }else{
        header('LOCATION:'.$this->sandbox_url.$vars);
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Add a product to the list
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   array
 * @return  void
 */
 function add($item_name = '',$item_amount = NULL,$item_qty = NULL,$item_number = NULL){
         $this->config['item_name_'.$this->item]     = $item_name;
         $this->config['amount_'.$this->item]        = $item_amount;
         $this->config['quantity_'.$this->item]      = $item_qty;
         $this->config['item_number_'.$this->item]   = $item_number;
         $this->item++;
 }
```

}
// END Paypal Class

/* End of file Paypal.php */
/* Location: ./application/libraries/Paypal.php */

[/CODE]

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve. Is the IPN notify_url unique for each user/store or there is just one URL for all of them?

Comment: @fat_mike There is just one url & function that handles the validation of the IPN and then puts the payment data into my database. What i'm looking to do is, if someone were to chargeback on a payment, it would run database tasks so I can "ban" that user from my service. Is the IPN url that is sent with the payment also used when a dispute is created on that payment. If not, is there a way I can go about this? Thank you